# Geolocation in Mozila Firefox: Both success and error triggered

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, geolocation

If I use geolocation in Mozilla Firefox and set timeout less then ca 7 seconds **(update - ca 4 seconds in FF 47.0.1)**, it returns both success and error (3 - Position acquisition timed out). If no timeout is set or is set long enough, it works OK (returns success). Tested in Mozilla Firefox 47.0 on Windows 7 and Android.
See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/fbqa8fuh/7/).

```
<h1>Geolocation test</h1>
<div id="results"></div>

<script>
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Let's begin<br>";

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionIs, positionIsNot, {
    enableHighAccuracy : false,
    maximumAge: 0,
    timeout: 4000
  });

  function positionIs(position) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "SUCESS: " + position.coords.latitude + "; " + position.coords.longitude + "; " + position.coords.altitude + "<br>";
  }

  function positionIsNot(err) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "ERROR: " + err.code + " " + err.message + "<br>";
  }

</script>
```

There is no problem in other browsers.
Do I something wrong or is it bug?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in the version 47+, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283563